# Line breaks in html table

Tags: html, html-table

How can I stop my table from increasing width every time I insert loooong commentary?

I made a simple example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table width='350'  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th id="row_style" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>ID</th>
                <th id="row_style" width= "50%" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>Content</th>
                <th id="row_style" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="row_style" bgcolor='#3399FF' scope='col' width='50'>Example</td>td>
                <td id="row_style" width ='10%'> Content</td>td>
                <td id="row_style" bgcolor='#3399FF' scope='col' width ='10%'>Example</td>td>
                <td width ='10%'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I increase the word "content" the table width is increasing.. how can I stop this and insert a line break?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this by setting a width for the table and you could also use

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

In order to prevent really long words to break out of boundaries.

Width is best set in css:

Edit: include

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Demo

http://jsbin.com/atonut/1/edit

```
table {
width:500px;
table-layout:fixed;
}


td {
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

If your problem is a lot of text rather then incredibly long words, only use width, and leave the word-wrap out. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 15):

Sounds terrible but you should use:

```
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style:

```css
td
{
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    padding: 5px;
}
th
{
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    padding: 5px;
}
/* @media print
{
    table
    {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}*/
```

Give style to tr:

```css
style="page-break-inside: avoid;"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer :

```
<table width='350'  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th id="row_style" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>ID</th>
                    <th id="row_style" width= "10%" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>Content</th>
                    <th id="row_style" bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>Date</th>

                </tr>
<tr>
                            <td id="row_style" bgcolor='#3399FF' scope='col' width='10%'>Example</td>
                            <td id="row_style" width ='10%'> Contentd</td>
                            <td id="row_style" bgcolor='#3399FF' scope='col' width ='10%'>Example</td>
                            <td width ='10%'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without any explanation, it is difficult to see at a glance what is different in your answer (from the original). Also, it is not formatted consistently, which makes it difficult to read. Also, it contains closing body and html tags but no opening, missing td close tag and missing table close tag. It might be a good answer (with some explanation), currently it is hard to tell.